# Visual Studio 2010 Version Control Without Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure-devops

Since I started to program in Visuel Studio and have experience of TFS in my last Project, I wanted to know, if I can use version control on my local machine?

Since I don't work in a team and I cannot acces the old TFS (because it was from my university), it would be cool, if there is a feature in Visual Studio 2010, which allows version control locally.

As I never used Version Control, I am not very used to alternatives and would like to keep it simple with a Visual Studion Build in solution.

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common solution for a single developer is to use some free version control solution, like SVN, Mercurial or Git. All of them make it easy to set up your own repository, or you can use some hosting provider (some providers provide free hosting for small projects). SVN can integrate into Visual Studio using AnkhSVN and the user experience will be a lot similar to the MS Team solution.

Answer (score 0):

Tfs always involves a server but if you want avoid the need for one I'd recommend you look at the hosted on demand version

http://tfspreview.com/

To note, typically you wouldn't want all your version control local as it you'd lose the benefit of code being backed up remotely.  That said you might want to explore distributed version control systems like git which give you the benefits of local storage and remote masters (I'd recommend [github:windows](http://windows.github.com/))

Answer (score 0):

With the release of Team Foundation Server 2012 there is also an expression edition of TFS called [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-team-foundation-server-express).

You can download it for free [here](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) (located under Visual Studio Express 2012 and then Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Express 2012).

[Here is a blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bharry/archive/2012/02/23/coming-soon-tfs-express.aspx) by Brian Harry where he announces the product.

If you don't want to install a server product on your local machine, you can have a look at the Team Foundation Service: http://tfspreview.com/

I use it for my own personal projects and it works perfectly. Currently it's still in beta and it's completely free. Prices are not announced yet but probably there will be a free account option for small usage.